# What am I doing wrong on reproducing CID's hash digest in ipfs dag-cbor

Tags: ipfs

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51655352/how-recreate-a-hash-digest-of-a-multihash-in-ipfs), which is about how the hash digest in the ProtoBuf-based MerkleDag (`dag-pb`) format is computed. Since the `ipfs dag` will replace `ipfs object`, and CBOR will be supported, here I want to ask the similar thing about `dag-cbor`. I tried to find the answer in IPFS's documentation but did not get much information.

So I did the following.

```sh
$ echo '[0,1,2,3]' | ipfs dag put
```

It gives the CID `bafyreidiu4acrauzpzhefghkkom6pbbsvw34o7kc2trpnqd7l62yrxrv2q`. 
In the IPFS webui, the CID is resolved as

```
bafyreidiu4acrauzpzhefghkkom6pbbsvw34o7kc2trpnqd7l62yrxrv2q
base32 - cidv1 - dag-cbor - sha2-256-256-68a7002882997e4e4298ea5399e78432adb7c77d42d4e2f6c07f5fb588de35d4
BASE - VERSION - CODEC - MULTIHASH
MULTIHASH
0x122068a7002882997e4e4298ea5399e78432
      adb7c77d42d4e2f6c07f5fb588de35d4
HASH DIGEST
0x12 = sha2-256
0x20 = 256 bits
```

I expect the `[0,1,2,3]`is first serialized by CBOR as a CBOR-array, then sha256 digested.
Therefore I want to reproduce the hash digest (`68a700288299...`). So I did the following in Python's repl:

```
>>> from cbor2 import dumps
>>> from hashlib import sha256
>>> from binascii import hexlify
>>> hexlify(sha256(dumps([0,1,2,3])).digest())
b'e3fbd65c4c3f7fdba7b8ae0709da781c3637b13f4a4b920db90d2f9b23d412ff'
```

So the hash cannot match. But if I do the same thing for a simple string object, i.e.,

```
$ echo '"Hello World"' | ipfs dag put
bafyreidfq7gnjnpi7hllpwowrphojoy6hgdgrsgitbnbpty6f2yirqhkom
```

the hash digest, in this case, can be successfully reproduced.

So why it doesn't work for the array object (map objects fails as well)? What else is hiding?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found [github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/issues/6549](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/issues/6549). So that's because go-ipfs parses `[0,1,2,3]` as float64. So in Python if I change it to `[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]`, the two hash values match perfectly! That's also why the simple string works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it might be a wrong data type representation in Python. Have you tried a tuple instead?

Comment: Just tried. A tuple `(0,1,2,3)` in Python will be treated as a CBOR array as well by the cbor2 package. So it gives me the same result. I also compared the Python cbor-dumped result with http://cbor.me/. They are the same.